# Rails 4, ActionMailer: dynamic config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer

For a client who wants a contact form in his Rails 4 app, I need to set up ActionMailer config, but allow him to change the config (address, password, smtp...) from a backoffice such as activeadmin or a simple admin interface.

I don't know where to start with that to access to the environment.rb or production.rb file to change these settings.

Or if it's possible to set up ActionMailer in another file which would be accessible and with the possibility to set up dynamic variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rails-settings-cached gem

https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached

Or

You can create a config table and allow admin to save his configuration settings like

rails g model Config field_one:string field_two:string field_three:string

after that in you development/production.rb

you can use as Config.first.first_field, Config.first.last_field

and make sure when you update the values of the column, don't make new record, just update the last one.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I like your second approach. But, for example to replace : config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: smtp.address, user_name: 'myusername', password: 'mypassword'  }. Isn't it too deep? Or can I do something like rails g model Config address:string and call It inside the config.action_mailer.smtp_setting = { address: Config.address... } and so on?

Comment: you can not call Config.address directly, either you have to make class methods like
def self.address
  last.address
end
now you can call Config.address directly.
Thanks, if you find my answer helpful for you, just give an upvote

Comment: It works, and don't at the same time. I had to put the actionmailer setting in a initializers, and every time I change the settings which are in the DB, I need to restart the server (because of the initializer). I also tryied to deploy to heroku, but to many error. I'm looking for other options. If you have any suggestion? Thanks